# Karma with Mocha, Chai, Chai-as-promised and chai-sinon

Tags: karma-runner, karma-mocha, chai-as-promised, sinon-chai

I'm trying to get my Karma test suite running with Mocha, Chai, Sinon, Chai-as-promised and chai-sinon.

It's currently set up with just mocha, chai and sinon framework.

```
frameworks: ['mocha', 'requirejs', 'sinon', 'chai']
```

Now I've tried adding some additional karma plugins, namely the karma-chai-sinon and karma-chai-as-promised.  Then changing the above to

```
frameworks: ['mocha', 'requirejs', 'chai-sinon', 'chai-as-promised', 'chai']
```

In my unit test I have

```
expect(stub).to.not.have.been.called();
```

but this gives me an error 'TypeError: '[object Object]' is not a function...'
But if I do

```
expect(stub.called).to.equal(false);
```

It works as expected.

I've tried inspecting the karma plugin code but can't make any sense of them,  I expected somewhere in the karma plugin to say 'chai.use(chaiAsPromised)' and 'chai.use(sinonChai)' but they don't.
Karma website doesn't really explain how plugin/frameworks work under the hood either.

Can anybody help me set this up?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

By default, any assertions that don't take arguments have to be declared without brackets:

```
expect(stub).not.to.have.been.called;
```

(Yeah it's weird.)

That's because in this case `called` is a getter function which actually sets up the assertion when it's *accessed*.

If you want to call these assertions as functions using parentheses you can use a plugin like [dirty-chai](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dirty-chai) (and [karma-dirty-chai](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-dirty-chai)).